# What percentage of employees fail the test? Percentage of those fired were innocent?

Tags: probability

To reduce theft among employees, a company subjects all employees to lie-detector
tests and then res all employees failing this test. In the past, the test has been proven
to correctly identify guilty employees 95% of the time; however 8% of the innocent
also fail the test. Suppose that 20% of the employees are actually guilty.

What percentage of employees fail the test? What percentage of those fired were innocent?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem

Comment: It's worth noting, though irrelevant to your problem, that 95% is much higher and 8% much lower than the actual rates for polygraph tests.  No comment on the 20%!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Out of 100 employees, how many are guilty?  How many innocent?  Of the innocent, how many fail?